# How to see whether modal is open in Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap. If a modal is open, I'd like to display `true`. If it's not open, I'd like to display `false`. Is there a way to do this within the HTML?

I tried using the following code, but it's wrong:

```
<code>myForm.$modalStack.opened={{myForm.$modalStack.opened}}</code>
```

Any thoughts on how to do this correctly?

Below the relevant code I'm using to trigger the modal:

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="myForm.agreement()">
```

Code in Controller:

```
.controller('MyFormCtrl',
  function ($location, $stateParams, $modal, $scope, $http) {
    var myForm = this;
    // . . . 

   myForm.agreement = agreement;

   function agreement() {

       $modal.open({

          templateUrl: 'views/agreement.html'
  })
});
```

Comment: where are you calling the modal to open and all that. please show that code

Comment: @ajmajmajma I added the relevant code. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Answer added, you will have to set $modal open to a var and then set another boolean to trigger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `opened` property returned by `$modal.open` is a promise you can hook into.

So, using their example, see here - http://plnkr.co/edit/PsEqTIy8CDUU88HMLxbC?p=preview

```
$scope.modalOpen = false;
$scope.open = function (size) {
    var modalInstance =  $modal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.opened.then(function () {
        $scope.modalOpen = true;
    });

    // we want to update state whether the modal closed or was dismissed,
    // so use finally to handle both resolved and rejected promises.
    modalInstance.result.finally(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.modalOpen = false;
    });
};
```

You want to call the promises and then do whatever you need. `.opened` is a promise for when the modal opens, and `.result` is a promise for when the modal closes. So using this idea, you would use `$scope.modalOpen` as your boolean.