# How to tell if angularjs modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out if a modal is opened or closed.  But I'm getting the error can not read property of open. I understand have to hook in to the $modal.open and get the result.  I've been using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594640/how-to-see-whether-modal-is-open-in-angular-ui-bootstrap) as an example but still getting the error. My intentions if this modal is open then I can not open the next prompt.  But if the modal is closed then I have another modal prompt to open.  Dont know if just looking at it to long but any suggestions are welcome.  Thank you

Here is the modal code from another modal.js file :

```
    function openSerialEntry($modal, $scope, item, onupdate) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "sales/partials/serialNumberEntry.html",
        size: "med",
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false,
        controller: serialNumberCtlr,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        resolve: {
            item: function () { return item; },
            onupdate: function () { return onupdate; },
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        onupdate(result);
    }, function () {

    });
}
```

Here is my controller where just trying to set a variable:

```
   $scope.modalOpen = false;

    commonModals().openSerialEntry().opened.then(function () {
        $scope.modalOpen = true;
    });
```

Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at Object.openSerialEntry (modals.js:347)

Comment: Have you tried this? 
$(".modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                    $scope.modalOpen = true;
});

Comment: You should include the definition of your controller. We can't tell from here which function is the controller function. It looks like `openSerialEntry` is your controller function, but that's an odd name for a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not passing `$modal` to the function `openSerialEntry`, it's `undefined` and that's why you get an error `Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`. I suppose you need to inject `$modal` into your controller and pass it to `openSerialEntry`. Also, you're not returning anything from `openSerialEntry` function so the next error would be `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Here is the code that fixes these problems:

```
function openSerialEntry($modal, $scope, item, onupdate) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "sales/partials/serialNumberEntry.html",
        size: "med",
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false,
        controller: serialNumberCtlr,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        resolve: {
            item: function () { return item; },
            onupdate: function () { return onupdate; },
        }
    });

    return modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        onupdate(result);
    }, function () {

    });
}

yourcontrollerfunction.$inject = ['$modal'];

commonModals().openSerialEntry($modal, $scope, item, onupdate).then(function () {
    $scope.modalOpen = true;
});
```

Comment: @TroyBryant, did my answer help?

Comment: worked like a charm thanks - made a few tweaks for all the suggestions and got it working

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the dependency on the module with the $modal service in your app module.